# Compound index order based on field selectivity

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-indexes

I have two fields *a* and *b*, where *b* has substantially higher selectivity than *a*.

Now, if I am only querying on both *a* and *b* (never on either field by itself), which of the following two indexes is better and why:

1. `{a: 1, b : 1}`
2. `{b: 1, a : 1}`

Explain seems to return almost identical results, but I read somewhere that you should put higher selectivity fields first. I don't know why that would make sense though.

Comment: I'd venture to guess that second index is better, but you need to test that. Run an explain on both queries.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev updated question... explain seems to be the same for both.

Comment: You know how they say, "if you can't see the difference, there's none". :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that may be the correct answer, wanted to see if I was missing something.

Comment: There is one thing, it could depend on how you query and what order you query, especially with sorts. For effective index usage a sort should be the last field in an index. However I too am unsure if what you read is true, at least I have never heard the case. I have heard and seen where the first field of a compound index must match the first field of the query, but that's about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some further analysis the two indexes are in fact pretty much identical from a performance point of view.

Really if you are in a similar situation, the real consideration should be whether in the future you might be more likely to query on *a* alone or *b* alone, and put that field first in the index.

Answer (score 4):

After some extensive work to improve queries on a 150 000 000 records database I have found out the following:

not necessarily higher selectivity fields, but actually fields that are "faster" to match, being moved to the first position can increase performance drastically

I had an index composed of the following fields:

zip, address, city, first name, last name

Address is matched by an array, not string = string so it takes most time to execute and is the slowest to match. My first index that I created was: **address_zip_city_last_name_first_name** and the execution time for matching 1000 records against the whole DB would go for hours.

Address field actually probably has the highest selectivity on these, but since it is not being matched by a simple string equality, it takes the most time. It actually goes something like this

```
{ address: {$all : ["1233", "main", "avenue] }}
```

By changing this index to having the "faster" fields in the beginning, for example: **zip_city_first_name_last_name_address** the performance was much better. The same 1000 records would match in just one second instead for going for hours.

Hope this helps someone

cheers

Answer (score 0):

I believe the optimiser will choose the index best to use, although you can provide hints

e.g.

```
db.collection.find({user:u, foo:d}).hint({user:1});
```

see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization

Comment: Although this is true, it is quiet a generic answer applicable to pretty much **any** Mongo scenario and query. Unfortunately it's not very helpful for this specific question.

Comment: fair point - but i was really suggesting using `hint()` so you could  compare the performance each index? (i haven't btw) - but logically it makes sense to index first the least selective attribute, then you have fewer records to sort or sub filter. ultimately though your index should reflect the queries you want to perform. Apologies if answer wasn't helpful anyway.